# Writing scaleable code

Tags: concurrency, distributed, distributed-computing

Can someone describe in very simple terms how you would scale up a service (lets assume the service is very simple and is the function X() ).

To make this scalable would you just fire off a new node (upto a maximum depending on your hardware) for each client who wants to run X?

So if I had four hardware boxes, I may fire up to four nodes to run service X(), on the 5th client request I would just run X() on the first node, the 6th client on the second node etc?

Following on from this, I know how to spawn processes locally, but how would you get both the 1st and 5th clients to use the same Node 1- would it be by spawning a process remotely on the Node for the Client each time?

Any simple examples are most welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want a technique to round robin through the nodes? If yes, you can just cycle through the list using Nodes = [node() | nodes()], lists:nth(length(Nodes) - (Counter rem length(Nodes)), Nodes). Or something like that.

Comment: @Isac, Im just interested in which functions and basic code one would need to offload tasks onto remote nodes, as you would when scaling up code. So my function X() if I wanted to run X() on different boxes, how would I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This depends very much on what X is. If X is fully independent, for instance `x() -> 37.` then you don't even need to connect your nodes. Simply place some standard Load Balancer in front of your system (HAProxy, Varnish, etc) and then forget about any kind of distributed communication. In fact, there is no need to use Erlang for that. Replace Erlang with some other language of your choice. It is equally good.

Where Erlang shines is when several X functions have dependencies on each others result and when the X might live on another physical machine. In that case Erlang can communicate with the other X seamlessly, even if it lives on a different node.

If you want to implement a round-robin scheme in Erlang, the easiest way is to have a single point of entry and then let it forward the requests out to multiple nodes. But this is bad if there is a pattern where a certain node ends up with all the long-running processes. You need to build a mechanism of feedback so you know how to weight the round-robin queue.